# Mekler’s construction!

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I was looking at this [slides](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~chernikov/slides/Barcelona2017.pdf) by Artem Chernikov. But I did not understad what Mekler’s construction is exactly.

Can one explain the idea of Mekler’s construction (in model theory) in a simple words? Thank you!

Comment: In general, questions of the form "explain this technical piece of math to me" are not the best use of this site. Can you focus your question more? For one thing, it's not clear to me whether you're asking about *what* Mekler's construction does, or *how* it does it.

Comment: Also, it's hard to imagine an answer here giving more detail than a full set of slides on the subject. So what issue *in particular* do you not understand or want more detail about? (Note that the *what* question is addressed on pages 3-4, and the *how* question is addressed on pages 15-19 of the slides).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I just wanted to know what Mekler's construction is via a simple example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to read about Mekler's construction is Hodges's big book *Model Theory*.

The construction proceeds in two steps:

1. From a structure $A$ in a finite relational language, produce a "nice" graph $C_A$ (here "nice" has a precise definition) which is bi-interpretable with $A$. Hodges works this out in detail in Theorem 5.5.1.
2. From a "nice" graph $C$, look at the nilpotent class 2 group of exponent $p$ (for a fixed prime $p$) $G(C)$ presented by generators and relations, where the generators are the vertices of $C$ and the relations say that two generators commute if and only if they are connected by an edge in $C$. So explicitly, we take the free group generated by $C$ and quotient by the normal subgroup generated by (a) $x^p$ for all $x$, (b) $[[x,y],z]$ for all $x,y,z$, (c) $[a,b]$ for all generators $a,b\in C$ which are connected by an edge in $C$. Here $[x,y]$ is notation for the commutator $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.

The analysis of this group $G(C)$, showing that it reflects the model theoretic properties of $C$ (and hence of $T$ if $C = C_A$ where $A\models T$) is carried out in Appendix A.3 of Hodges.

---

In the comments, you ask for a "simple example". The problem is that even if you start with a very simple theory $T$, stage 1 of the above construction produces a big ugly graph. And then the definition of $G(C)$ in terms of generators and relations in stage 2 is as concrete a description of this group as you're going to get. So there's not much more to say about examples.

If you're having trouble with the abstractness of the definition of $G(C)$, it could be instructive to take a small finite "nice" graph $C$ (like the one which is just two points connected by an edge) and try to understand the group $G(C)$. Similarly, you could try to understand stage 1 by taking a small finite structure $A$ in a language with just one or two relation symbols, and drawing the picture of $C_A$.

Comment: Maybe for the model theory you still need the nice graphs, but for a reduction from graphs to groups, He & Qiao https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.07200 recently proved that one does not need to use nice graphs as an intermediary: one can construct G(C) directly from a graph C as in Mekler, and $C \cong C'$ iff $G(C) \cong G(C')$.